# Magick++ CORE_RL_Magick++_.dll NOT FOUND

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magick++

Visual Studio Express 2010. When writing some simple code, like:

```
    InitializeMagick("D:\Programming\Visual Studio 2010\ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16");
Image image;
image.read( "1.png" );
image.crop( Geometry(100,100,100,100) );
image.write( "2.png" );
```

i have a runtime standart windows error (system windows7 x64) with text like "CORE_RL_Magick++_.dll not found. Try to reinstall the program". I have this file from binary release, but VS cant see it:(

What have i do to solve this?

I want to use Magick++ to make some png files from matrix of RGB pixels, so if you have any easier ways to make this, say be, i will be gratefull=)

Comment: Did you copy all the .dll files from the binary release to the folder you use with InitializeMagick ?

Comment: Yes, after install, all dll files are in this location

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when your project cannot find the necessary dlls to link.So you have to copy all dll files with suffix _RL from Imagemagick folder to your project folder.Here _RL refers to release version.Another option is to change your output directory to bin folder of Imagemagick.
Thanks

Comment: I changed my post build event to copy in all the DLL's from the ImageMagick install directory and it worked :)